# How to convert pixel values of an image array to white or black only?

Tags: image, image-processing

I would like to convert the image below to only black and white (no gray areas).

So, if I have the variable "image_array" (shape 12288x1 double, values ranging from 0 to 1), how can I convert all the values in this array so that they are either 0 or 1 only? The threshold could be if a value is <0.5, then its new value=0. Otherwise, its new value=1.

I was thinking of just doing this: create a for loop to iterate through each value in "image_array" and, with an if statement, to compare the current value against the threshold & assign its new value? Or, is there a simpler way, more efficent way to do this?

[image]

Comment: `bin_array=zeros(size(image_array));bin_array(image_array>0.5)=1;`

Comment: Or just `+(array>0.5)`. The comparison returns a logical array. The unary plus turns the logical array into a numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image [Processing and Computer Vision Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/help/overview/image-processing-and-computer-vision.html), you can simply use [`imbinarize`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html). It does global thresholding according to Otsu's method or adaptive thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

Let `A` be the image mentioned in the question:

```
th1=.5;
A(A>th1)=1;
A(A<=th1)=0;
```